# Change child <div> style under a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using a React component like this

```
const teststyle={color:red}
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
        <ParentComponent 
          mainContent={
           <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
           </ul>}
         >
         </ParentComponent>
   }
}
```

The `<ParentComponent>` will automatically generate a `<div>` tag for props: `maincontent`. So  the final render result is sth like

```
    <ParentComponent>
      <div class="testtest">
        <ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </ParentComponent>
```

Image I have a test style defined inside `</ParentComponent>`

I am trying to change css style for the `<div>` when click list item.
How can I get the `div dom` and apply style on it in `<ParentComponent>` file?

thanks!

Comment: Please create a codesandbox

Comment: I guess you do not have control over ParentComponent, right? can you add some class to the div?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got what you want but... Isn't recommended access DOM elements using React. If you want to change a style for the div use a event instead, like onClick for each element, and that event has to change the current style for the div.

Answer (score 0):

if  component generates automatically then its props also can generate with it you can set style there as `<div style={this.styleChanger}></div>` and then follow as down below

create a state like this

```
state = {
  styleChange: true
}
```

then make a function as shown below. i know this looks ugly but this is for demo

```
clicker = () => {
    if (this.state.change) {
      this.setState({
        styleChange: false
      });
      return {
        backgroundColor: "red"
      };
    } else {
      this.setState({
        styleChange: true
      });

      return;
    }
  };
```

here call function onClick and set function as style it will automatically executed

```
  <ParentComponent>
      <div style={this.styleChanger}>
        <ul>
         <li onClick={this.clicker}>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </ParentComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The  will automatically generate a  tag for props: `maincontent`

This will only happend if inside `ParentComponent` there is a `div` surrounding it like

```
<div>
    {this.props.children}
</div>
```

If this is your case, you should use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
<Fragment>
    {this.props.children}
</Fragment>
```

OR

```
<>
    {this.props.children}
</>
```

So just change `ParentComponent` to use Fragment and add your own div element with the style you want.

```
<ParentComponent>
  <div style={this.styleChanger}>
    <ul>
     <li onClick={this.clicker}>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</ParentComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you do not have control over the Parent Component I suggest you do as following

---

- use a state to define when you need to apply style
- wrap all in a div with your own class
- when state changes then add a custom class
- add a rule for your custom class

---

.component-wrapper--clicked > div{...}

---

```
<div className={`component-wrapper component-wrapper--${this.state.isClicked ? 'clicked': ''}`}>
  <ParentComponent
    mainContent={
      <ul>
        <li onClick={() => this.setState({isClicked: true})}>1</li>

      </ul>
    }
  />;
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, right I dont have control over `ParentComponent`, I can only pass content to the `mainContent` props. There is a className for the `div` tag, modified code above. I am thinking maybe can use `React Refs` to get the `div` dom?

Comment: then my solution may help since you have control on the div outermost

Comment: since you do not have control over the ParentComponent then it is likely impossible to use refs to reference to that div.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. In your case create something like:

```
const createMainContent = () => {
    return {
        __html: '<ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>'
    };
```

Then pass it to your `<div />`:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMainContent()} />
```

Comment: I think your answer is not relevant to the question since div is automatically added by the parent component and the question is about how to change style of div when clicking on its children